# Need to update missing info in mySQL table column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm back again. Been searching and trying this for hours... Haven't found an answer or even the right question.

I want to fix a crashed table that I recreated from memory (and the members list in Works) using an query in phpMyAdmin. I need to populate each members total posts.

forum_messages

```
member_id  | message |
--------------------
1          |      Hello  |
3          |      One, Two, Three  |
1          |      Howdy!  |
2          |      Here we are again!  |
2          |      To answer your question...  |
```

forum_members

```
member_id  | posts |
--------------------
1          |      0  |
2          |      0  |
```

From forum_messages, forum_members should end up looking like this:

forum_members

```
member_id  | posts |
--------------------
1          |      2  |
2          |      2  |
3          |      1  |
```

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add that I only want to do this once and then upload the fixed table or entire database sql to the server again. Better yet, I could run this online before someone posts again and no one would be the wiser. Except members that noticed that they are newbies again. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
UPDATE forum_members SET posts = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_messages where forum_messages.member_id = forum_members.member_id GROUP BY forum_messages.member_id)
```

Comment: no problem. btw, you should use something like COUNT(Your_table_Primary_Key) instead of COUNT(*) when possible. it's better.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good tip. Well, let's mark this one answered.

Answer (score 1):

Using an INSERT SELECT query, you should be able to rebuild the data you had lost in the forum_members table.

This would return the number of messages per member_id:

```
SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) FROM forum_messages GROUP BY member_id;
```

Collating it with an INSERT query puts it into the table instead of displaying the data as it normally would in an SELECT query.

```
INSERT INTO forum_members (member_id, posts) SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) FROM forum_messages GROUP BY member_id;
```

Comment: Can you add some descriptive text to this answer to explain how it solves Fisherman's problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.. Please note that the code is **NOT TESTED**. You should echo the outcome of the update query to check if it's correct before executing the update query

```
$get_memberid = "SELECT distinct(member_id) as member_id FROM forum_members;";
    $Rget_memberid = mysql_query($get_memberid) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row_get_memberid = mysql_fetch_array($Rget_memberid))    {
        $arr_get_memberid[] = array( "member_id"    => $row_get_memberid['member_id'] );
    }

for ($c = 0; $c < count($arr_get_memberid); $c++){
    $update_count = "UPDATE forum_members set posts = (SELECT count(member_id) from forum_messages where member_id = '".$arr_get_memberid[$c]['member_id']."') where member_id = '".$arr_get_memberid[$c]['member_id']."';";
        $Rupdate_count = mysql_query($update_count) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I'll do it on my local machine and if it works, on the server. I'll let you know Guzzie. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work. I changed "SELECT distinct(member_id) to "SELECT distinct(ID_MEMBER). I didn't put the right column name in my question. The rest looked okay so I ran it. Got this error:Error

SQL query: Documentation

$get_memberid = "SELECT distinct(ID_MEMBER) as member_id FROM forum_members";

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$get_memberid = "SELECT distinct(ID_MEMBER) as member_id FROM forum_members"' at line 1

Comment: Strange. If I run the query in my phpadmin it doesn't give any errors and outputs the correct values. mysql fields are case sensitive so maybe try id_member instead of ID_MEMBER

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just to count messages by members, isn't it?

If so, use this SQL:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE forum_members;
INSERT INTO forum_members(member_id, posts)
 SELECT member_id, COUNT(1) FROM forum_messages GROUP BY member_id;
```

Comment: Well, it sort of did it. It updated the post counts but emptied all of the other cells. LOL Good thing I had a backup.